# Facebook SDK v4 Login PHP - multiple pages

Tags: php, html, facebook, authentication, sdk

I want to add Login with Facebook button to my WebPage. I logged successfully with SDK v4.0.

But I only logged within the same page. ($helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(SAME_PAGE))

Here is my code(loginFB.php). It works fine, but my question is:
How can i include this PHP in an other page (defaultLogin.php). I cannot see $session var form there, it logs in (because its returning to my defaultLogin.php with ?code=FACEBOOK_AUTH_CODE), but i cannot see the session.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

loginFB.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'logout'){
    $session->destroySession();
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    unset($session);
}

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'config/fbconfig.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;


// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(APP_ID,APP_SECRET);

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://myWeb/defaultLogin.php' );

try{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}catch(Exception $e){
    //echo "Facebook error: ". $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($session)){
    $_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
    echo "Login Successful<br>";
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    $graph2 = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();



    echo "Id: " . $graph->getId() . "<br>";
    echo "Hi " . $graph->getName() . "<br>";
    echo "Email: " . $graph2['email'] . "<br>";
    // print profile data
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graph2, 1 ) . '</pre>';

    echo "<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/".$graph->getId()."/picture?type=large' border=0>";

    echo "<script> checkUser('".$graph->getId()."','".$session->getToken()."','".$graph2['email']."'); </script>";

    echo '<a href="?action=logout">Logout</a>';


}
else{
    echo "<a href = " . $helper->getLoginUrl(array( 'email', 'user_friends' )) . ">Login con Facebook v1</a>";
}


if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);

    try{
        $session->Validate(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);
    }catch(FacebookAuthorizationException $e){
        $session = '';
    }
}
?>
```

defaultLogin.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" lang="es" conduit_compatibility_version="1" style="margin-top: 0px; position: relative !important;"><!--<![endif]--><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <?php include 'head.php';?>   

(...)

<?php include 'header.php';?>  
<?php include 'navLogin.php';?> (...)
```

navLogin.php

```
<?php include_once('loginFb.php')?>
 <!-- Navigator BAR -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container"> (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing few classes in your code . you need to add the following classes to your code before the line  use `Facebook\FacebookSession;` and it should be working .

```
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
```